# Not a problem but using object to achieve a task

Tags: discussion, scope

I have asked the question [Using electricity at night](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/7468/using-electricity-at-night) which has been put on hold with the reason

> "This question doesn't seem to be about a problem. — Questions should ask how to solve a problem using everyday objects. Questions requesting new ways to use an object are off-topic unless a problem to solve can be demonstrated."

Being a member of several SE sites, I have learned to read the Tour and I considered the question to be on-topic because

> Questions asking for unusual ways of using everyday objects to achieve a certain task [...]

The everyday objects in my case could be anything that uses electricity. The unusual way is to use it at a different time than normally.

Since I'd like to learn what questions to ask on LifeHacks, could someone explain why my question isn't on topic for the reason I picked? Is it not unusual enough? Should I ask how to use a washing machine without electricity instead?

Answer (score 3):

The main part of your question was this:

> What kind of electric devices in private households are most suitable to operate during night so that I can save electricity expenses?

This isn't a a problem, however, since you're not looking to complete one specific task.

A question along the lines of "How to do laundry without electricity?" would be welcomed on the site.